# nginx redirect to varios directories

Tags: nginx

I am looking for a way redirect the URLrequest to various directories.

For example the user calls server.com/get.php

I want it randomly be redirected to server.com/a/get.php, or  server.com/b/get.php or  server.com/c/get.php etc.

I know there is a way to use

```
upstream myapp1 {
        server srv1.example.com weight=3;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }
```

for redirecting requests to various servers. But could I do the same with directories?

Updated:
should it be this?:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $variant$uri $variant$uri/ $variant/index.php;
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this more easily with nginx's [split clients module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html).

For instance, if you want a roughly three way split:

```
http {
    split_clients "${remote_addr}AAA" $variant {
        33%     "/a";
        33%     "/b";
        *       "/c";
    }
```

Then in your `server` block, replace:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

with:

```
    try_files $variant$uri $variant$uri/ $variant/index.php;
```

Comment: thanks. I updated my ansqwer.. so should I include "try_files" into location part of the server block?

Comment: No, that should replace the `try_files` in your _other_ `location` block, the `location /` block.

Comment: It's incorrect. OP wants it randomly be redirected, but hashing $remote_addr would not make it random.